# Deleting large number of rows of an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a data table from company which is of 250Gb having 35 columns. I need to delete around 215Gb of data which 
is obviously large number of rows to delete from the table. This table has **no** primary key.

What could be the **fastest method to delete data from this table**? Are there any tools in Oracle for such large deletion processes?

Please suggest me the fastest way to do this with using Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is said in the answer above it's better to move the rows to be retained into a separate table and truncate the table because there's a thing called `HIGH WATERMARK`. More details can be found here http://sysdba.wordpress.com/2006/04/28/how-to-adjust-the-high-watermark-in-oracle-10g-alter-table-shrink/ . The delete operation will overwhelm your `UNDO TABLESPACE` it's called.

The `recovery model` term is rather applicable for mssql I believe :).

---

hope it clarifies the matter abit.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dou you know which records need to be retained ?  How will you identify each record ?

A solution might be to move the records to be retained to a temp db, and then truncate the big table.  Afterwards, move the retained records back.

Beware that the transaction log file might become very big because of this (but depends on your recovery model).

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem a long time ago.  Had a table with 1 billion rows in it but had to remove a very large proportion of the data based on certain rules.  We solved it by writing a Pro*C job to extract the data that we wanted to keep and apply the rules, and sprintf the data to be kept to a csv file.

Then created a sqlldr control file to upload the data using direct path (which wont create undo/redo (but if you need to recover the table, you have the CSV file until you do your next backup anyway).

The sequence was

- Run the Pro*C to create CSV files of data
- generate DDL for the indexes
- drop the indexes
- run the sql*load using the CSV files
- recreate indexes using parallel hint
- analyse the table using degree(8)

The amount of parellelism depends on the CPUs and memory of the DB server - we had 16CPUs and a few gig of RAM to play with so not a problem.

The extract of the correct data was the longest part of this.
After a few trial runs, the SQL Loader was able to load the full 1 billion rows (thats a US Billion or 1000 million rows) in under an hour.